# divided each column by date difference to calculate daily average value

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with columns like this

df.columns=['2021-01-01','2021-01-02',....'2021-05-01']

I'd like to calculate average daily rate

so firstly I create a new dataframe using cumsum(), then I'd like to divided cumsum() by date difference with the first date

How to do it? Thanks

```
df.columns=['2021-01-01',2021-01-02',....'2021-05-01']
df_cum=df.copy()
df_cum=df_cum.cumsum(axis=1)

df_avg=df_cum.copy()
df_avg=df_avg.apply(lambda: row: row/( current column date-first column date))
```

The calculation result looks like this below figure:
[image]
I am not sure how to do the last line? I am always confused by apply function since I am not sure which column it was applied to? anyone can help me, Thanks

Comment: can't you just use the basics functions of pandas to calcuate the Average of each column:

`df.mean(axis=0)` ?

Comment: no, that will create a single value,

Comment: I'd like to every colume has a average value and the average value is calculated from column value divided by date difference with first column. Is it clear? Thanks

Comment: not really to me, sorry... maybe a short example of the result you want to get would help ?

Comment: Hi Lu, yes I just added a excel screenshot to show calculation. Thanks

Comment: basically, I need to access column name inside apply function, I am not sure how to do it? for example, each cell= cell value/( column name(date) of this cell- column name(date) of first column)

Comment: @roudan, the answer I provided below does that, by multiplying the entire row with another series of the same size (the values of the first row) - I mistakenly wrote a solution applying to rows, but I added a solution for columns, which is very similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make explicit copies of a dataframe before performing an operation, but that is not needed. Methods like `.cumsum()` return a new copy of the dataframe with the operation applied.

Here's a version that does what you ask for:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [10, 20, 30, 40],
    [100, 200, 300, 400],
    [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000],
])
df.columns = ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04']


df_cs = df.cumsum()
initial_row = df_cs.iloc[0]
df_rates = df_cs.apply(lambda row: row / initial_row.values, axis=1)
print(df_rates)
```

The line `initial_row = df_cs.iloc[0]` takes the first row of the `df_cs` dataframe, so we can use the values later as `initial_row.values` (i.e. `[1, 2, 3, 4]`)

You say you're confused by `.apply()` because you're unclear what column it modifies - the way it is used here, it takes a `row` as the function argument and expects that function to return a new row (so it affects all columns, if the function touches all of them, as in this case). In this case, since we multiply by a series of values that is just as long as the original row, we get a new row with the same length. Thus, `.apply()` creates another new dataframe with the same dimensions as the original (`df_cs` in this case).

The call to `.apply()` also takes the argument `axis=1` because you want to apply this operation to each row, not each column.

Result:

```
   2021-01-01  2021-01-02  2021-01-03  2021-01-04
0         1.0         1.0         1.0         1.0
1        11.0        11.0        11.0        11.0
2       111.0       111.0       111.0       111.0
3      1111.0      1111.0      1111.0      1111.0
```

By the way, a (bad) habit I often see in new programmers is that they like to keep copies of everything they achieved around "just in case". The example above does this as well - once it is done, you have three copies of the data, in `df`, `df_cs` and `df_rates`. You made a few more copies still in your own example.

Don't be afraid to overwrite previous copies - that allows Python to free up the memory used previously by the old copy and allows your script to process greater quantities of data, without requiring more resources.

This works just as well:

```
df = df.cumsum()
initial_row = df.iloc[0]
df = df.apply(lambda row: row / initial_row.values, axis=1)
print(df)
```

But of course, in this case I've overwritten the original `df`, which you may need for another operation later on in the script.

And finally, if you like the readability of the original, but still like the idea of cleanup after the work, a function is the way to go:

```
def compute_rates(df):
    df_cs = df.cumsum()
    initial_row = df_cs.iloc[0]
    return df_cs.apply(lambda row: row / initial_row.values, axis=1)


print(compute_rates(df))
```

Edit:

From your example, I think I misunderstood - you want the difference by column, not by row. The same solution applies though:

```
def compute_rates_cols(df):
    df_cs = df.cumsum()
    initial_col = df_cs.iloc[:, 0]
    return df_cs.apply(lambda col: col / initial_col.values, axis=0)


print(compute_rates_cols(df))
```

The difference is that `df_cs.iloc[:, 0]` selects the first column and `axis` is now `0` (which means you could omit it, as that's the default)

Result:

```
   2021-01-01  2021-01-02  2021-01-03  2021-01-04
0         1.0         2.0         3.0         4.0
1         1.0         2.0         3.0         4.0
2         1.0         2.0         3.0         4.0
3         1.0         2.0         3.0         4.0
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much Grismar! I really appreciate your help.  but sorry I might not be clear, can I change the initialrow in your code to to column name difference. For example, timedelta(2021-01-01,2021-01-01),  timedelta(2021-01-02,2021-01-01), timedelta(2021-01-03,2021-01-01), timedelta(2021-01-04-2021-01-01).  My original issue was I don't know how to access column name. Thanks for your help

Comment: Grismar, inspired by your code, I modified like this:  ```initial_row_1 = pd.to_datetime(df_cs.columns),  initial_row_2=[]
for col in initial_row_1:
    initial_row_2.append((col-initial_row_1[0]).days), then I do this  df_rates = df_cs.apply(lambda row: row / initial_row_2, axis=1)

Comment: You're welcome to add an answer of your own (can be really brief, with just the solution you ended up with and maybe just a comment or two) and accept that, if you feel that's the correct answer - or you can accept a given answer to mark the question as answered.